# flutter build failed due to new gradle version problem

Tags: flutter

Launching lib\main.dart on M2101K7AG in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not download bundletool-0.14.0.jar (com.android.tools.build:bundletool:0.14.0)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/bundletool/0.14.0/bundletool-0.14.0.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/bundletool/0.14.0/bundletool-0.14.0.jar'.
> > No such host is known (dl.google.com)
> Could not download kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.3.50.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.3.50)
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-compiler-embeddable/1.3.50/kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.3.50.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-compiler-embeddable/1.3.50/kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.3.50.jar'.
> > jcenter.bintray.com
> Could not download fastutil-7.2.0.jar (it.unimi.dsi:fastutil:7.2.0)
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/7.2.0/fastutil-7.2.0.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/7.2.0/fastutil-7.2.0.jar'.
> > No such host is known (jcenter.bintray.com)

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 14s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are facing this problem from latest android studio..

android-studio-2020.3.1.23

5 Steps:

1. Set the JDK version to Embedded JDK

For MAC:

Android Studio > Preferences... > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle Under Gradle JDK

choose the Embedded JDK option. Click OK.

For windows:

select File > Settings... > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle Under Gradle JDK

choose the Embedded JDK option.

2. config jvm option Since version 9, the Java compiler can be configured to produce bytecode for an older Java version while making sure the code does not use any APIs from a more recent version. Gradle now supports this release flag on CompileOptions directly for Java compilation. This option takes precedence over the properties described below.
   Due to a bug in Java 9 that was fixed in Java 10, Gradle cannot leverage the release flag when compiling with Java 9.
3. click on Project Structure (folder with 3 dot icon next to Stop icon).
   Project Structure --> Project Settings --> Project

under Project SDK: Select Android API 30 Platform

click Apply --> OK

4. click on Project Structure (folder with 3 dot icon next to Stop icon).
   Project Structure --> Project Settings --> Modules

click + icon --> Apply --> OK

5. Use latest Gradle

This should solve..